# QR code life span

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, qrcode

Once the QR code is generated, how long is the code good for 24 hours, 48 hours?  I googled for the answer with no success.

Thank you

Comment: Could you be more specific in what context the QR code was issued?

Comment: I am going to send someone (that I know personally) money using a bitcoin QR code via Bitcoin ATM machine.  When the person sends me the QR code to use at the bitcoin ATM machine, what is the lifespan of that QR code 24 hours or longer?

Answer (score 3):

A QR code encoding…

- a payment request specific to some **payment provider** is subject to the specific payment provider's terms of use. A typical range could be between a few hours and a day.
- an on-chain **Bitcoin address** remains valid indefinitely. Although address reuse is not recommended, it could be used for multiple payments.
- a **Lightning Invoice** will be valid until the invoice times out (often 1h) or the invoice gets paid.